# How to validate signature in Soap UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

This is part of my request.

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
 <SignedInfo>
   <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
   <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <Reference URI="">
     <Transforms>
       <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
     </Transforms>
     <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
     <DigestValue>srfthsrfthsth</DigestValue>
   </Reference>
 </SignedInfo>
 <SignatureValue>srftjzasrthuust</SignatureValue>
 <KeyInfo>
   <X509Data>
     <X509IssuerSerial>
       <X509IssuerName>qwwe</X509IssuerName>
       <X509SerialNumber>123</X509SerialNumber>
     </X509IssuerSerial>
     <X509Certificate>assdf</X509Certificate>
   </X509Data>
 </KeyInfo>
```

I need to validate xml signature in Soap UI using groovy.
How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried validating from request editor of soapui by using `Alt+v` key combinations? Also you can check an [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257039/validating-a-signature-of-a-soap-message) which is `java`.Of course, you should be able to run the same from groovy script.

Comment: @Happy digital signature validation is not trivial... you must validate the signature correctness and the validation of the certificate (with CRL, OCSP)... there are also so different formats and requeriments (xmldsig, XAdES for your case) with different forms (enveloped, enveloping, detached)... you can try using XMLSecurity but with this you only validate the signature integrity but not the certificate validity.