# Java XML DOM - how to use Element.getAttributeNS

Tags: java, xml, xmldom, wss4j, xmlsec

I have XML node:

```
    <soapenv:Body 
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
        wsu:Id="Id-223">
         ....
    </soapenv:Body>
```

What values should I pass to org.w3c.dom.Element.getAttributeNS(namespaceURI, localName) to get the value of attribute Id?

**Note** I can use Element.getAttribute("wsu:Id") to get the value but **I have to use getAttributeNS method**.

**Additional Info:** [org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.token.Timestamp](https://www.javatips.net/api/wss4j-master/wss4j-trunk/ws-security-dom/src/main/java/org/apache/wss4j/dom/message/token/Timestamp.java) uses following code:

```
public  String getID() {
   //WSConstants.WSU_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    return element.getAttributeNS(WSConstants.WSU_NS, "Id");
}
```

I can confirm this piece of code does not work.

[my code] was copied from Dmitry's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257039/validating-a-signature-of-a-soap-message/9443960). You can easily reproduce my error using the XML in question and validateSignature method in Dmitry's answer

```
File signatureFile = new File("/home/user1/Downloads/test.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(signatureFile);

Node securityNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("wsse:Security").item(0);
Node bodyNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:Body").item(0);
validateSignature(securityNode, bodyNode, key);
```

Then

```
public boolean validateSignature(Node signatureNode, Node bodyTag, PublicKey publicKey) {
        boolean signatureIsValid = false;
        try {
            // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to unmarshal the
            // document containing the XMLSignature
            String providerName = System.getProperty
                    ("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
            XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM",
                    (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

            // Create a DOMValidateContext and specify a KeyValue KeySelector
            // and document context
            DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new X509KeySelector(publicKey), signatureNode);

            String nameSpaceURI = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
            org.w3c.dom.Element bodyEle = (Element) bodyTag;
            System.out.println(Main.nodeToString(bodyEle));

            valContext.setIdAttributeNS((Element) bodyTag, org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants.WSU_NS, "Id");



            // Unmarshal the XMLSignature.
            XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
            // Validate the XMLSignature.
            signatureIsValid = signature.validate(valContext);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return signatureIsValid;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're not opening the soap body and attempting to getAttributeNS on the full payload?

To clarify. is `element` a `SOAPBody/SOAPElement`?

Comment: @shinjw The value of element is <soapenv:Body...>, just as expected. I have confirmed it via 2 different ways.

Comment: I'm asking about the Java class of element. My hunch is that you are using the wrong part of the SOAP message to pull out the value.

Comment: @shinjw it is org.w3c.dom.Element

Comment: You'll need to supply more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I missed this piece of code

```
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```